# Assign a value to a shape, in Python

Tags: python, scipy, python-imaging-library

Is there a way, in a picture:

1. to detect a shape (eg. a circle).
2. to relate the shape with its location on the picture (eg. left, right, center) and to assign a value (true or false).

I think that there is a solution using PIL and SciPy, but do not know where to start. any tips?

Thanks and sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) for this.

Python bindings for it [already exist](http://code.google.com/p/pyopencv/) (they are not very pythonic though) so it shouldn't be too hard to get into it.

Comment: It seems that OpenCV is exactly what I'll need to develop the project. Thank you!

Comment: The question is old, but in fact what I was looking for is more or less what that the project of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.3834) does.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [SimpleCV](http://simplecv.org/doc/). I have recently found it. It is very easy way how to deal with opencv in python. They have also [examples](http://examples.simplecv.org/en/latest/index.html). There is also detection library attached.

Answer (score 0):

We've tried to make it quite easy in SimpleCV.

```
import SimpleCV

img = SimpleCV.Image('foo.png')
blobs = img.findBlobs()
circles = blobs.filter([b.isCircle() for b in blobs])
```

now circles is just a list, each object in that list is a feature and has all the relevant information like x,y,area,color,etc.